# Validations API REST in Spring Boot 3 application don't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

My REST API tests work correctly, but I'm having problems performing validations to show messages that the user is not entering the correct values, how do I solve this? For example, description should return a message saying that `Description is required`, but return me `Status: 400 Bad Request` in `POST` and `PUT` method.

- `pom.xml`

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

- `TypeHunterModel.java`

```
package com.user.springboot3.project.Model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
@Table(name="type_hunters")
public class TypeHunterModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Description is required")
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    public TypeHunterModel() {  // No-arg constructor for JPA

    }

    public TypeHunterModel(int id, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
    public String getDescription() { return description; }
    public void setDescription(String description) { this.description = description; }
}
```

- `TypeHunterDAO.java`

```
package com.user.springboot3.project.DAO;

import com.user.springboot3.project.Model.TypeHunterModel;

import java.util.List;

public interface TypeHunterDAO {
    TypeHunterModel create(TypeHunterModel theTypeHunterModel);
    TypeHunterModel update(TypeHunterModel theTypeHunterModel);
}
```

- `TypeHunterServiceImplementation.java`

```
package com.user.springboot3.project.Service;

import com.user.springboot3.project.DAO.TypeHunterDAO;
import com.user.springboot3.project.Model.TypeHunterModel;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import jakarta.persistence.TypedQuery;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class TypeHunterServiceImplementation implements TypeHunterDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public TypeHunterServiceImplementation(EntityManager theEntityManager) {
        this.entityManager = theEntityManager;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public TypeHunterModel create(TypeHunterModel theTypeHunterModel) { // POST: localhost:8080/api/type-hunter
        entityManager.persist(theTypeHunterModel);
        return theTypeHunterModel;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public TypeHunterModel update(TypeHunterModel theTypeHunterModel) { // PUT: localhost:8080/api/type-hunter
        TypeHunterModel typeHunterModel = entityManager.merge(theTypeHunterModel);
        return typeHunterModel;
    }

}
```

- `TypeHunterREST.java`

```
package com.user.springboot3.project.REST;

import com.user.springboot3.project.DAO.TypeHunterDAO;
import com.user.springboot3.project.Model.TypeHunterModel;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RequestMapping("/api")
@RestController
public class TypeHunterREST {

    private TypeHunterDAO typeHunterDAO;

    public TypeHunterREST(TypeHunterDAO theTypeHunterDAO) {
        this.typeHunterDAO = theTypeHunterDAO;
    }

    @PostMapping("/type-hunter")
    public TypeHunterModel create(@RequestBody @Valid TypeHunterModel typeHunterModel) {
        return typeHunterDAO.create(typeHunterModel);
    }

    @PutMapping("/type-hunter")
    public TypeHunterModel update(@RequestBody @Valid TypeHunterModel typeHunterModel) {
        return typeHunterDAO.update(typeHunterModel);
    }

}
```

I specified my dependencies and files above.

Comment: Without validations tests work, with validations tests don't work.

Answer (score 0):

By default Spring returns what you are seeing when validation fails. You need to create a custom exception handler annotated with `@RestControllerAdvice` that has a method that handles `MethodArgumentNotValidException`, the exception thrown when validation fails. This exception handler can format the response to your liking. See [this](https://medium.com/@mibatman01/spring-boot-validation-and-exception-handling-2023-edition-5df8c0c5ec6a) for exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think your validation is working as expected and `400 Bad Request` indicates it, you need to handle this exception properly.

You can do something like this:

```
    @RestControllerAdvice
    public class GeneralExceptionController {

        @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
        public ResponseEntity<?> getIncorrectAmount(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            exception.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().forEach(error -> {
                map.put(error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage());
            });
            return map
        }

    }
```

Just make sure that you get `MethodArgumentNotValidException` exception.

If you don't want to create `ControllerAdvice` you can add the exception handler directly to your controller, it's up to you.